# Marshalling C++ Struct Containing Enums to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, interop, marshalling

The following C++ struct needs to be marshalled to C#. It represents input from a Tablet touch sensor coming in as wm_tablet_flick message. As a result I am trying to process those messages in a C# application:

```
    typedef struct FLICK_DATA {
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE iFlickActionCommandCode  :5;
      FLICKDIRECTION          iFlickDirection  :3;
      BOOL                    fControlModifier  :1;
      BOOL                    fMenuModifier  :1;
      BOOL                    fAltGRModifier  :1;
      BOOL                    fWinModifier  :1;
      BOOL                    fShiftModifier  :1;
      INT                     iReserved  :2;
      BOOL                    fOnInkingSurface  :1;
      INT                     iActionArgument  :16;
    } FLICK_DATA;
```

Where:

```
    typedef enum FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE {
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_NULL          = 0,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_SCROLL        = 1,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_APPCOMMAND    = 2,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_CUSTOMKEY     = 3,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_KEYMODIFIER   = 4 
    } FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE;
```

And:

```
typedef enum FLICKDIRECTION {
  FLICKDIRECTION_RIGHT       = 0,
  FLICKDIRECTION_UPRIGHT     = 1,
  FLICKDIRECTION_UP          = 2,
  FLICKDIRECTION_UPLEFT      = 3,
  FLICKDIRECTION_LEFT        = 4,
  FLICKDIRECTION_DOWNLEFT    = 5,
  FLICKDIRECTION_DOWN        = 6,
  FLICKDIRECTION_DOWNRIGHT   = 7,
  FLICKDIRECTION_INVALID     = 8 
} FLICKDIRECTION;
```

On the C# side I get:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FLICKDATA
    {
        internal FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE iFlickActionCommandCode;
        internal FLICKDIRECTION iFlickDirection;
        public bool fControlModifier;
        public bool fMenuModifier;
        public bool fAltGRModifier;
        public bool fWinModifier;
        public bool fShiftModifier;
        public int iReserved;
        public bool fOnInkingSurface;
        public int iActionArgument;
    }

    public enum FLICKDIRECTION
    {
      FLICKDIRECTION_RIGHT       = 0,
      FLICKDIRECTION_UPRIGHT     = 1,
      FLICKDIRECTION_UP          = 2,
      FLICKDIRECTION_UPLEFT      = 3,
      FLICKDIRECTION_LEFT        = 4,
      FLICKDIRECTION_DOWNLEFT    = 5,
      FLICKDIRECTION_DOWN        = 6,
      FLICKDIRECTION_DOWNRIGHT   = 7,
      FLICKDIRECTION_INVALID     = 8 
    }

    public enum FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE
    {
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_NULL          = 0,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_SCROLL        = 1,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_APPCOMMAND    = 2,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_CUSTOMKEY     = 3,
      FLICKACTION_COMMANDCODE_KEYMODIFIER   = 4 
    }
```

Then I determine the size of the structure as following:

```
private int _flickDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(new FLICKDATA());
```

And finally try to either convert pointer to structure using:

```
     FLICKDATA data = new FLICKDATA();
     data = (FLICKDATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.WParam, typeof(FLICKDATA));
```

Or use built-in GetLParam method:

```
     data = (FLICKDATA)m.GetLParam(typeof(FLICKDATA));
```

But neither solution works and comes either empty or garbage. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried casting data? Instead of directly trying to access it like that? Or maybe create a pointer to FlickData. Also no data is random!/ Garbage its there for a reason you just need to understand why its there.

So yeah try create a pointer to FlickData or:

FLICKDATA* data = FLICKDATA;
Try that (maybe have to play around with it)

Try and cast Flickdata into your Data varible:
auto data(static_cast(FLICKDirection);